# VTK error message in ipython on CentOS 7

Tags: python-2.7, vtk

I am using a module called pymatgen (http://pymatgen.org). There is a function within pymatgen
which displayed a graphical representation of an structure object.  pymatgen requires VTK and
the VTK python bindings.  I have installed both on my CentOS 7 system.  Yum reports

> %yum list installed |grep -i vtk vtk.x86_64
>
> 6.1.0-5.el7                     @epel     vtk-python.x86_64
>
> 6.1.0-5.el7                     @epel     vtk-qt.x86_64
>
> 6.1.0-5.el7@epel     vtk-qt-python.x86_64@epel

in ipython (4.2.1)

```
In [1]:  import pymatgen as mg

In [2]:  from pymatgen.vis.structure_vtk import StructureVis

In [3]: struct = mg.Structure.from_file('POSCAR')

In [4]: StructureVis(struct)
```

> libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found libGL error:
>   failed to load driver: swrast
>   X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
>   Major opcode of failed request:  150 (GLX)
>   Minor opcode of failed request:  3 (X_GLXCreateContext)
>   Value in failed request:  0x0
>   Serial number of failed request:  44
>   Current serial number in output stream:  45

I am confused by this error as VTK is installed. I am using the CentOS 7 machine via a 
  remote X11 client (on a Macintosh using Mac OS X 10.11.5). 
  Does anyone have a suggestion as to how to resolve this problem as it is preventing me from using the visualization environment.